# Xvfb: GLX error when using nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, xvfb

I would like to run some headless unit tests, my problem can be recreated with just glxinfo. I try to run:

```
xvfb-run glxinfo
```

It prints multiple lines about GLX:

> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":99".

If I try to run Xvfb on background:

```
Xvfb :99 &
```

It prints list of extensions, GLX is also there:

> Initializing built-in extension GLX

But still, running:

```
DISPLAY=:99 glxinfo
```

Gives same GLX error.

It happens only when I use nvidia driver (tested on 352 and 340 proprietary from repository). Same command works fine after switch to Nouveau.
Is this a nvidia package problem? Is there a better way to run xvfb in this case?

Comment: What is the exact reason for you to run 'xvfb-run glxinfo'?

Comment: I have tests that open some windows. On my CI server, tests run in xvfb. I would like to have the same approach locally. Clicking somewhere (changing focus) can change test results.

Comment: 'xvfb-run glxinfo' gives same GLX error as 'xvfb-run my-tests'.